# How to pull data from an element outside of a loop using a common field

Tags: xpath, xslt

I'm looping through XML using XSL but some of the fields I need to reference sit outside of my loop and are dependent on an ID from the current element, there is a common ID field that I can use to match up the elements but I'm unsure on how I can reference this or join this data together.

```
<Company><Employee_Stack_Grouped>
<Employee_Stack>
<Employee>
  <Changes sequence='0'>
    <Details>
      <EmployeeID>ABC11111</EmployeeID>
    </Details>
    <Plans>
      <Plan updated='Y'>
        <Name>Plan 1</Name>
        <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
        <ID>12345</ID>
      </Plan>
      <Plan updated='Y'>
        <Name>Plan 2</Name>
        <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
        <ID>67890</ID>
      </Plan>
      <Plan>
        <Name>Plan 3</Name>
        <Start>01/01/2023</Start>
        <ID>11111</ID>
      </Plan>
      <Interest_Plan updated='Y'>
        <Name>Plan 4</Name>
        <Start>13/10/2023</Start>
        <ID>22222</ID>
      </Interest_Plan>
    </Plans>
    <Amounts>
      <Earning  updated='Y'>
        <Amount>1000</Amount>
        <Plan>
          <ID>12345</ID>
        </Plan>
      </Earning>
      <Earning updated='Y'>
        <Amount>1000</Amount>
        <Plan>
          <ID>67890</ID>
        </Plan>
      </Earning>
      <Earning>
        <Amount>100</Amount>
        <Plan>
          <ID>11111</ID>
        </Plan>
      </Earning>
      <Earning updated='Y'>
        <Amount>5000</Amount>
        <Plan>
          <ID>22222</ID>
        </Plan>
      </Earning>
    </Amounts>
  </Changes>
</Employee>
</Employee_Stack></Employee_Stack_Grouped></Company>
```

I am outputting all of the updated Earning Nodes but I need to get the relevant date from the plans element which sits outside of my current loop, additionally, there's different child elements within Plans. Im not sure if my approach is correct, I will have have multile Employees/ mulitple changes per employee that I need to loop through. Any ideas appreciated?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
exclude-result-prefixes="xs xsi"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
version="3.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:template match="Employee_Stack_Grouped">
    <File>
        <Header>
            <Employee_Number>EMP</Employee_Number>
            <Date>Start_Date</Date>
            <Amount>Amount</Amount>
            <ID>ID</ID>
        </Header>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Employee_Stack"/>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee_Stack">
    <xsl:for-each select="Employee">
        <xsl:for-each select="Changes">
            <xsl:variable name="employeeID" select="Details/EmployeeID"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="Amounts/Earning[@updated = 'Y']">
                    <row>
                        <Employee_Number><xsl:value-of select="$employeeID"/></Employee_Number>
                        <Date></Date>
                        <Amount><xsl:value-of select="Amount"/></Amount>
                        <ID><xsl:value-of select="Plan/ID"/></ID>
                    </row>
                </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT has a built-in [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#key) mechanism for resolving cross-references. In your example, it could work along the lines of:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="plan" match="Plans/Plan" use="ID" />

<xsl:template match="/Company">
    <File>
        <Header>
            <!-- header data -->
        </Header>
        <xsl:for-each select="Employee_Stack_Grouped/Employee_Stack/Employee/Changes">
            <xsl:variable name="employeeID" select="Details/EmployeeID"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="Amounts/Earning[@updated='Y']">
                <row>
                    <Employee_Number>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$employeeID"/>
                    </Employee_Number>
                    <Date>
                        <xsl:value-of select="key('plan', Plan/ID)/Start"/>
                    </Date>
                    <Amount>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Amount"/>
                    </Amount>
                    <ID>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Plan/ID"/>
                    </ID>
                </row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

To include the `Interest_Plan` in the key, change its definition to:

```
<xsl:key name="plan" match="Plans/Plan | Interest_Plan" use="ID" />
```

Comment: This works for the approach I have presented above but in my attempt of censoring the XML I laid it out slightly incorrectly. (The details node sits outside of changes / I could have multiple plan nodes with the same ID within Plans).  Doing some testing with the correct XML this approach doesn't quite work, it's able to make the match but due to multiple nodes with the same ID it's pulling multiple values where the match is made. Additionally does this work with XSL 3?, I was using streaming but it threw an error due to the node must be in a tree whose root is a document node.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question and post a representative XML example and stress the fact that you are using streaming. Also if a match on ID is expected to fetch multiple plans, clarify how to determine which plan is the one you want.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask another question. Marked this as the answer as it works for my provided XML